# int isn`t iterable python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create the Cows and Bulls game, but getting a `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. Here is my code:

```
import random

print('You are playing Cows and Bulls game !')

number = random.randint(1000,2000)
number = list(number)
print(number)
user_number = input('Guess a number : \n')
global cows, bulls
cows = 0
bulls = 0
user_number = list(user_number)
print(user_number)

def game():
 if user_number[0] in number:
    cows += 1
 elif user_number[1] in number:
    cows += 1
 elif user_number[2] in number:
    cows += 1
 elif user_number[3] in number:
    cows += 1
 elif user_number not in number:
    bulls += 1

game()
```

When I start the program it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Cows and
        number = list(number)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I don't know what to do, please help, and I'm just starting out so there might be some dumb mistakes, if so make sure to correct me :)
I assume it wants me to make it a string or what ?

Comment: `number` is a single integer. `in number` requires `number` to be an iterable (*multiple* values).

Comment: so, what do I need to edit ?)

Comment: provide a sample input and output

Comment: it didnt work, now it tells me : name 'np' is not defined

Comment: import numpy as np

Comment: I`ve done that but it gives me a bunch of numbers, but I want 1 number to guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have attempted to turn an `int` into a `list`. `int`s are not iterable, which is a requirement for the `list()` function to work. You can make your code work by just changing `number = list(number)` to `number = list(str(number))`, but just `number = str(number)` will work as well.

Comment: thanks man !! you saved my so much time, greatly appericate your answer ! :)

Comment: @СтепанБандера no problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

`list()` convert an iterable (tuple, string, set, dictionary) to a list. An iterable is an object that you can get an iterator from and an int is not an iterable.

Thus `number = list(number)` will throw a `TypeError` exception. So will `user_number = list(user_number)` if the input is not an iterable.

If your intention is to generate numbers and push them into a list, I'd modify the code to be:

```
import random

print('You are playing Cows and Bulls game !')

number = [random.randint(1000,2000)]
# also below works:
# number = list()
# number.append(random.randint(1000,2000))

print(number)

user_number[input('Guess a number : \n')]
# also below works:
# user_number = list()
# user_number.append(input('Guess a number : \n'))

global cows, bulls
cows = 0
bulls = 0
print(user_number)

def game():
 if user_number[0] in number:
    cows += 1
 elif user_number[1] in number:
    cows += 1
 elif user_number[2] in number:
    cows += 1
 elif user_number[3] in number:
    cows += 1
 elif user_number not in number:
    bulls += 1

game()
```